# how to use awk to add empty line between non-consecutive lines

Tags: awk

I have the following input file,

```
time-1 message-a
time-2 message-b
time-3 message-c
time-4 message-a
time-5 message-b
time-6 message-c
```

I want to generate output with line number and an empty line between non-consecutive line. How can I do so?

Expected output,

```
1 time-1 message-a
2 time-2 message-b

4 time-4 message-a
5 time-5 message-b
```

I tried the following, but still can't figure out the empty line.

```
awk '/message-a/,/message-b/ {print NR, $0}' input.txt
```

Comment: How are lines 3 and 6, non-consecutive here? Are you always only wanting `message-a` and `message-b` lines printed and the others removed (changed to blank)? Your example or your description is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
BEGIN {
   a="";
   n=0
}

/.*message-a/ {
   a=$0
   n=NR
   next;
}

/.*message-b/ {

   if( a != "")
   {
      print n, a;
      print NR, $0;
      print ""
      next;
   }
}

// {
 a=""
}
```

and

```
awk -f test.awk data
```

with data being

```
time-1 message-a
time-2 message-b
time-3 message-c
time-4 message-a
time-5 message-b
time-6 message-c
time-7 message-a
time-8 message-c
time-9 message-b
time-0 message-a
time-a message-b
time-b message-c
```

produces:

```
1 time-1 message-a
2 time-2 message-b

4 time-4 message-a
5 time-5 message-b

10 time-0 message-a
11 time-a message-b
```

Note that we skipped the line starting with `time-7` because it is not immediately followed by a `message-b` line.

The idea is to save the line with `message-a` and its line number. Then check if the next line contains `message-b`. If a different line occurs, we reset a because `message-a` is not followed by `message b`.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the solution,

```
awk '/message-a/ { print "\n" NR, $0 } /message-b/ { print NR, $0 }' input.txt
```